# Count most record from tow columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello i have a table (Spiel), where i have two Columns (SpielerIDForderer, SpielerIDGefordert). From this two col i want the record which occurs most
and count it together. So if the value/id 2 comes two times at SpielerIDForderer and seven times at SpielerIDGefordert, it should return 9.

This is my table

```
+-------------------+--------------------+
| SpielerIDForderer | SpielerIDGefordert |
+-------------------+--------------------+
|  5                |  2                 |
|  3                |  2                 |
|  3                |  2                 |
|  3                |  8                 |
|  6                |  2                 |
|  3                |  2                 |
|  3                |  2                 |
|  2                |  3                 |
|  2                |  2                 |
+-------------------+--------------------+
```

And this is my SQL which is not working correct:

```
SELECT SUM(dum.tab) AS total FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(SpielerIDForderer) AS tab FROM pddb.Spiel AS b
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(SpielerIDGefordert) AS tab FROM pddb.Spiel AS a WHERE SpielerIDGefordert=SpielerIDForderer
) AS dum
```

My expected result in this case is **9**

Comment: Please add your desired result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT value, count(*) AS total FROM (
    SELECT SpielerIDForderer AS value FROM pddb.Spiel AS b
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SpielerIDGefordert AS value FROM pddb.Spiel AS a
) AS dum
group by value
order by total desc
limit 1
```

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
select id, count(*) as counting from 
(
select SpielerIDForderer as id from table
union all
select SpielerIDGefordert from table
) as t group by id
```